# swift 3 error : Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads on UICollectionViewLayout (Spinning wheel)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewlayout

I am new to programming and I am trying to make a Circular effect to CollectionView, I have the following:

```
 override func prepare()
{
    super.prepare()

    let centerX = collectionView!.contentOffset.x + (collectionView!.bounds.width / 2.0)
    attributesList = (0..<collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)).map { (i)
        -> CircularLayoutAttributes in
        // 1
        let attributes = CircularLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: IndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0))
        attributes.size = self.itemSize
        // 2
        attributes.center = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: self.collectionView!.bounds.midY)
        // 3
        attributes.angle = self.anglePerItem*CGFloat(i)
        return attributes
    }
```

But I get the error : Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads, like on the picture, what am I doing wrong?

[image: Pic1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax has changed with Swift 3.

Use:

`IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)`

Comment: You're welcome, you might have the same issue with other methods as well ( typically : `CGRectMake(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)` which is now `CGRect(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)` )